# How can i capture command(ctrl on windows)+ numpad plus/minus using react hotkeys library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hotkeys

I'm using react hotkeys library to implement all hotkeys/shortcuts in my react app using the following keymap.js to try to capture command(ctrl on windows)+ numpad + and command(ctrl on windows)+ numpad -...but the browser is refusing to capture such key combo and accordingly the functionality written to handle these events is not executed.

It's working with many other key combos like the following examples:

```js
  ADD_ONE_FRAME_TO_START_TIME: {
    hotkey: '+',
    key: '+',
    location: 3,
    keyCode: 107,
  }

  FOCUS_LAST_EVENT: {
    hotkey: 'Shift+PageDown',
    key: 'PageDown',
    location: 0,
    keyCode: 34,
    shiftKey: true
  },

  SEEK_TEN_SECONDS_BACKWARD: {
    hotkey: 'alt+meta+4',
    key: '4',
    location: 3,
    keyCode: 52,
    metaKey: true,
    altKey: true,
    hotkeyType: 'video'
  },
```

But specifically not capturing cmd/ctrl + (numpad plus) and cmd/ctrl + (numpad minus) key combos. Any thoughts how to fix this?

```js
  ADD_ONE_FRAME_TO_END_TIME: {
    hotkey: 'meta+add',
    key: '+',
    location: 3,
    keyCode: 107,
    metaKey: true,
  }

  DECREASE_ONE_FRAME_FROM_END_TIME: {
    hotkey: 'meta+subtract',
    key: '-',
    location: 3,
    keyCode: 109,
    metaKey: true,
  }
```